# Odd Hex Length in String after converting string to Hex

Tags: c#

I need to send a message through the server. The message parameters are:
**MsgTitle** and **MsgBody**. 
I need to convert the message from the buffer to Hex but I get the error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Input string
>   '64756D6D7920746578742068657265' is not a valid number.

Here is the JSON data I'm using:

```
var json = @"{
Mess: [
      {
      Msg: {
            MsgTitle: " + hex + @",
            MsgBody: " + hex + @"
           }
      }
      ]
}";
```

The code I've implemented to solve the issue:

```
string msg = "dummy text here";
byte[] utfBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(utfBytes).Replace("-", "");
```

I also tried a lot of HEX converter functions which I've found here but it seems none of them are working and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Also, I was told that only characters allowed in URLs are permitted.

Comment: could you please show how your above json look by debugger. means replacing actual values with variable name `hex`?

Comment: by observing JohnSkeets answer you should use class object to prepare your json so these error will not be anymore in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON includes properties like this:

```
MsgTitle: 64756D6D7920746578742068657265,
MsgBody: 64756D6D7920746578742068657265
```

That's how you represent *numbers*. For *strings*, you need quotes, like this:

```
MsgTitle: "64756D6D7920746578742068657265",
MsgBody: "64756D6D7920746578742068657265"
```

Additionally, the names of the properties should be in quotes too:

```
"MsgTitle": "64756D6D7920746578742068657265",
"MsgBody": "64756D6D7920746578742068657265"
```

The simplest way of avoiding problems like this is to not construct the JSON directly as a string in the first place. Instead, use a JSON API such as Json.NET. Here's sample code to do that with an anonymous type, although there are various other ways too:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string msg = "dummy text here";
        byte[] utfBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(utfBytes).Replace("-", "");

        var obj = new
        {
            Mess = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    Msg = new
                    {
                        MsgTitle = hex,
                        MsgBody = hex
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Mess": [
    {
      "Msg": {
        "MsgTitle": "64756D6D7920746578742068657265",
        "MsgBody": "64756D6D7920746578742068657265"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That's now valid JSON - and much easier code to get right.

Comment: Hi Jon! I already did what you suggested by doing this:  
'MsgTitle': '" + hex + @"',
'MsgBody': '" + hex + @'" 
But if I do so then nothing happens. Getting exception of invalid message.

Comment: @CarlosFlorian: Well with no more information than "Getting exception of invalid message" we can't really help you. But at least that's valid JSON. It may or may not be what your server expects - we don't have any information about that. Again though, I'd *strongly* advise you not to construct the JSON yourself like this. It's really brittle.

Comment: I think I can get it working! I only have the JSON from the API and need to build the app. Unfortunately, there is no additional information. But your code is just pretty perfect and helped to learn more. I can work around it.

Comment: I managed to solve it right now! Thank you Jon! What a lesson I've just learned!